# Is an integral domain with two prime ideals necessarily a DVR?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My intuition tells me no, but I couldn't think of an example. A counterexample would of course have to be an infinite, non-Noetherian non-PID.

Comment: Imagine a semi-local integral domain with Krull dimension $1$ and two maximal ideals.

Comment: Consider perhaps the ring of algebraic integers over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Answer (score 0):

It is not. I explain the counterexample of the non-discrete valuation ring $k[[x^{\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}}]]$ of formal power series with non-negative real exponents [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999012/constructing-a-local-non-noetherian-domain-with-spectrum-0-mathfrakm/2999043#2999043).